# IntelliJ IDEA 2017 - sbt 0.13.X not found

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I have a problem with IntelliJ IDEA 2017 and sbt. Though I don't use any proxy or something like this, I get the following error during every time I try to create new sbt project or create new one:

```
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.13 ...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
            module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.13

    ==== local: tried

      C:\Users\HN48DH\.ivy2\local\org.scala-sbt\sbt\0.13.13\ivys\ivy.xml

      -- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.13!sbt.jar:

      C:\Users\HN48DH\.ivy2\local\org.scala-sbt\sbt\0.13.13\jars\sbt.jar

    ==== Maven Central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.13/sbt-0.13.13.pom

      -- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.13!sbt.jar:

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.13/sbt-0.13.13.jar

    ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

      https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.13/ivys/ivy.xml

    ==== sbt-ivy-snapshots: tried

      https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.13/ivys/ivy.xml

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            :: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.13: not found

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
    SERVER ERROR: Parent proxy unreacheable url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.13/sbt-0.13.13.pom

    SERVER ERROR: Parent proxy unreacheable url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.13/sbt-0.13.13.jar

    SERVER ERROR: Parent proxy unreacheable url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.13/ivys/ivy.xml

    SERVER ERROR: Parent proxy unreacheable url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.13/ivys/ivy.xml


:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
unresolved dependency: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.13: not found
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
(see C:\Users\user-name\.sbt\boot\update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.13.13

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I really run out of ideas what might be wrong. I'd be grateful for Your help.

Comment: I solved it, but I don't know what was wrong. I installed Community Edition and sbt worked without issues there. Suprisinlgy, it also stared working in my Ultimate edition. So I suppose something was wrong with my low-level system settings or IDEA settings.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to help, if you go to the link from your error message:

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.13/sbt-0.13.13.pom

It gives me: "404 Not Found" so your IDE tries to download SBT from a wrong location. Maybe the repository location have changed.